# What privileges does a MySQL User need for Wordpress?

Tags: mysql, debian, wordpress

I need to create a new MySQL user to manage my wordpress site. What privellages are needed for wordpress?

I assume INSERT is also needed and maybe DROP?

Example

```
GRANT SELECT ON database.* TO user@'localhost';
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [official documentation](http://codex.wordpress.org/Installing_WordPress) says to give the user all privs. Others suggest that you can [restrict it to](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/wordpress-mysql-permissions?replies=4)

- SELECT
- INSERT
- UPDATE
- DELETE
- CREATE
- DROP
- ALTER
- INDEX

Plugins etc can though call any statement they want so you would have to thoroughly test everything you install if you restrict privileges.

Comment: SELECT seems pretty important.